# Search and replace links by correspondence array

Tags: php, regex, search, replace, domdocument

I want to search and replace links based on a correspondence array.

I wrote this solution but I find it a bit simplistic and maybe not efficient enough to handle 2000 pages and 15000 links. What do you think? Use DOMDocument or regex would be more effective? Thank you for your answers.

```
    $correspondences = array(
                    "old/exercise-2017.aspx" => "/new/exercise2017.aspx",
                    "old/exercise-2016.aspx" => "/new/exercise2016.aspx",
                    "old/Pages/index.aspx" => "/new/en/previous-exercises/index.aspx"
                   );

$html = '<ul><li><a href="old/exercise-2017.aspx">Appraisal exercise 2017</a></li><li><a href="old/exercise-2016.aspx">Appraisal exercise 2016</a></li><li> <a href="old/Pages/index.aspx">Previous appraisal exercises</a></li></ul>';

foreach($correspondences as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($html, $key)) {
        $html = str_replace($key, $value, $html);
    }
}
echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this just once, to edit the HTML pages?  Or at runtime when a page is served?

Comment: In fact, the html content is store in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is not the most efficient, but it should be fine as long as you do it only once and store the result.  Given that you have already implemented it this way, you should just go with it unless you run into an actual performance problem.

*If* you are trying to do this at runtime (i.e. modify the page every single time it is served) then, yes, this is likely to be problematic.  15000 string searches per page is likely to be slow.

In that case, the most obvious change would be the one implied by this answer: do it once and save the result, instead of calculating it at run time.

If you *must* do it at runtime, then the optimal solution would use `DOMDocument` to get the URL.  You could then replace it based on a set of rules if possible (e.g. if `/old/Pages/` always gets translated to `/new/en/previous-exercizes` then implement logic for that).  Or you could use a dictionary keyed to the old URL to get the new URL, if you must individually code each path.

Comment: I should have better explained where the data came from so I did not think I was doing it at runtime. All datas (old links, new links and content come from a database) with the idea to store new content with new links in the database then thank you for your answer.